# Time complexity for running len(array) in python?

Tags: python

How does Python find the length of the array? Is it stored somewhere in an internal data-structure or does it have to iterate through the entire thing to find the length?

I ask because I'm using it for a binary search which should run in O(log(n)), but this obviously doesn't make sense if I have to iterate through the whole thing just to find the length.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: For list is O(1), other types look here: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists can store their length as part of their structure. Since it only needs to be stored in one place, it can add a maximum of `O(1)` to all computations and therefore not be too much overhead.

Getting the length is therefore `O(1)` because it's just the lookup of a field.

For more information, see [the docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).