# Understanding python's len() time complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity

I had a question about whether I was understanding the time complexity of the `len` function in Python correctly. I've seen multiple posts on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670070/time-complexity-for-running-lenarray-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134512/what-is-the-secret-behind-pythons-len-builtin-time-complexity-of-o1) but I feel like the answers didn't explicitly answer another question I had.

As I understand it, the time complexity of calling the `len` function is `O(1)` because the length of the object (e.g. an array) is stored behind the scenes. However, the time complexity of calling a function that isn't stored behind the scenes (e.g. `max` or `min`) is `O(n)` because we would have to search the entire array.

I'm wondering then, would it be correct to also think of the time complexity of `len` to be `O(n)` (because it takes `n` number of constant operations to keep track of the length of the array as we add or delete values from the array) but is only `O(1)` because we keep track of the length behind the scenes?

Technically, we should be able to store other information such as `max` and `min` while we create the array and accessing this information would also be `O(1)` if we explicitly save these values.

Comment: An excellent proposal to save min and max value in list structure. These operations are the most calling operations on lists.

Comment: Keep in mind that lists aren't append-only; it would be trivial to track the min/max if they were, but once you open the possibility of invalidating the current maximum, things get more complicated (heaps are the standard solution to this, but do you really want every list to store a heapified copy of itself)...

Comment: "As I understand it, the time complexity of calling the len function is O(1) because the length of the object (e.g. an array) is stored behind the scenes." `len` is a generic function that will work on any type that *supports* it. That is most built-in container types, be it `list`, `dict`, etc but there is *nothing inherent* about `len` that is constant time, you *could* implement at type that uses whatever algorithm to retrieve a "length" for a container

Comment: "I'm wondering then, would it be correct to also think of the time complexity of len to be O(n) (because it takes n number of constant operations to keep track of the length of the array as we add or delete values from the array) but is only O(1) because we keep track of the length behind the scenes?" No, that is not correct. Each operation will have some time complexity, and usually, a constant additional time complexity to save the changed length of a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`len(obj)` simply calls `obj.__len__()`:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4].__len__()
4
```

It is therefore not correct to say that `len()` is always O(1) -- calling `len()` on *most* objects (e.g. lists) is O(1), but an arbitrary object might implement `__len__` in an arbitrarily inefficient way.

`max(obj)` is a different story, because it doesn't call a single magic `__max__` method on `obj`; it instead iterates over it, calling `__iter__` and then calling `__next__`.  It does this n times (and also does a comparison each time to track the max item it's seen so far), so it must always be at least O(n).  (It can be slower if `__next__` or the comparison methods are slow, although that would be very unusual.)

For either of these, we don't count the time it took to build the collection as part of the cost of calling the operation itself -- this is because you might build a list once and then call `len()` on it many times, and it's useful to know that the `len()` by itself is very cheap even if building the list was very expensive.

Answer (score 4):

Let's check it:

```
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def main():
    a = []
    data = []
    for i in range(10_000):
        a.append(i)
        ts_len = time.time()
        _ = len(a)
        te_len = time.time()

        ts_max = time.time()
        _ = max(a)
        te_max = time.time()

        ts_min = time.time()
        _ = min(a)
        te_min = time.time()

        data.append([i, te_len - ts_len, te_max - ts_max, te_min - ts_min])

    data = np.array(data)
    plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], "-r", label="len")
    plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 2], "--g", label="max")
    plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 2], ".b", label="min")
    plt.title("Len/max/min")
    plt.xlabel("Size of the list")
    plt.ylabel("Time elapsed (s)")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Len/min/Max]

Comment: Why is there a sudden rise between 6000 and 7000 list size?

Answer (score 3):

We don't count the complexity of all the operations that increment and decrement the length field of the array, because they're not dependent on the current length of the array.

For instance, if you build up an array by appending and popping, you may have done far more than `n` iterations before you call `len()`.

Furthermore, if you're calculating the complexity of the entire algorithm, you would have already accounted for the complexity of creating the array. You don't want to count it again when calculating the complexity of processing the array.